# Not able to initialize GUI for kali linux in wsl 2?

Tags: kali-linux, gui, dependencies, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This error message is being displayed:

```
TigerVNC Viewer 32-bit v1.10.80
Built on: 2020-06-15 22:33
Copyright (C) 1999-2020 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.

Wed Aug 19 23:22:57 2020
 DecodeManager: Detected 8 CPU core(s)
 DecodeManager: Creating 4 decoder thread(s)

Wed Aug 19 23:22:59 2020
 CConn:       unable to connect to socket: No connection could be made because
              the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

Also I tried running the installation again and the following error message follows:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good : Depends: libcaca0 (>= 0.99.beta17-1) but it is not going to be installed
 pulseaudio : Depends: libwebrtc-audio-processing1 but it is not going to be installed
```

I did try running : "sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-good pulseaudio" but it didn't work
Please help!

Comment: [WSL does **not** aim to support GUI desktops or applications (e.g. Gnome, KDE, etc.)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#can-i-run-all-linux-apps-in-wsl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried `kex --kill` with no success. I did `kex --stop` and it works!
Edited syntax to match new Win-Kex version

Comment: It worked in win10. Looks like the process ID is always on and needs to be stopped everytime or process is stored in memory.

Answer (score 2):

So I noticed on mine I got the same.  " CConn:       unable to connect to socket: No connection could be made because
the target machine actively refused it. (10061)"

I had to actually edit the kex file /usr/bin/kex and change the 127.0.0.1:1 to 127.0.0.1:2 as my session was spawned on 2 you can tell that on launch in the CLI

```
X DISPLAY #     RFB PORT #      PROCESS ID
:2              5902            8802
```

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error: " CConn: unable to connect to socket: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)" It appeared after first restart since I installed Kali. I tried `kex stop; kex` which opens a new display :2. I wanted to change kex file as suggested by @vam but I can not find it in /usr/bin/kex... Also I can not find any manual to kex. When I try `man kex` I just get "No manual entry for kex". Any ideas?

OK I just found **solution** [here:](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/kali-linux-gets-a-gui-desktop-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux/)
Before you start kex switch to your user home directory. Windows starts kali by default in /mnt/c/Users/yourusername . Just switch to home with `cd ~` and then type `kex`.

Answer (score 2):

**The following solution worked for me.**

Step1: Start **Powershell** or **Command Prompt** in **Administrator Mode**.

Step2: type **wsl** (if kali-linux is you default distro) or just type **bash**, press enter.

Step3: type **cd** or **cd ~**, press enter.

Step4: type **kex**, press enter.

**InshAllah** it will work fine.

Comment: The important point here, as Daniel Vavrik pointed out, is step 3 - that you need to start 'kex' from your home folder.

Comment: I understand that sometimes it feels this way, but God has nothing to do with this :)

Comment: @papadi, to you `It feels this way`
but to me `I believe this way`:)

Answer (score 1):

*For those who did not have any success with the above answers*

After experimenting a bit I think I understood the issue. There is some updated package that is causing issues with kex. Reinstall Kali, do NOT dist-upgrade, and directly do an apt update and apt install kali-win-kex and it will work just fine. Again, do not update the kali wsl2 system.

Comment: yep. this was actually the only update did to my distro. and now I can't connect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the dependencies it tells you aren't installed?

Try `sudo apt install libcaca0`
And `sudo apt install libwebrtc-audio-processing1`

Comment: I did. No good.

Answer (score 0):

In WSL terminal (kali) type

```
kex kill
```

this will stop kex server and kill all related processes.

Then try to launch `kex`, this would resolve the socket issue