# Not able to start a new kex session in kali linux for wsl2

Tags: kali-linux, gui, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I try to run kex in kali-linux for WSL2, following error message is thrown. There's no missing dependencies. I have tried all solutions listed in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605309/not-able-to-initialize-gui-for-kali-linux-in-wsl-2?newreg=775db72939d64a39a112177666703e23) thread, but none of it works for me. Any other suggestions will be really appreciated:

```
Win-KeX server sessions:

X DISPLAY #     RFB PORT #      PROCESS ID
:1              5901            584

You can use the Win-KeX client to connect to any of these displays.

randhir@LAPTOP-294HO1DB:~$
TigerVNC Viewer 32-bit v1.10.80
Built on: 2020-06-15 22:33
Copyright (C) 1999-2020 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.

Mon Aug 24 21:52:43 2020
 DecodeManager: Detected 4 CPU core(s)
 DecodeManager: Creating 4 decoder thread(s)

Mon Aug 24 21:52:45 2020
 CConn:       unable to connect to socket: No connection could be made because
              the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605309/not-able-to-initialize-gui-for-kali-linux-in-wsl-2 here is the answer, try to get to kex from win console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After experimenting a bit I think I understood the issue. There is some updated package that is causing issues with `kex`.

Reinstall Kali, **do not** `dist-upgrade`, and directly do an

```
apt update
apt install kali-win-kex
```

and it will work just fine. Again, *do not update the kali WSL2 system*.

Answer (score 0):

Just open Kali, become root, and

```
kex stop
```

Then try again. you have to manually kill the server each time.

Answer (score 0):

Just run it with `sudo`: start Kali and type

```
sudo kex
```

By doing this you can still use `kex` in WSL2 and dont have to resist installing WSL2. Also keep in mind that you have to manually kill the server as already stated by another answer by running

```
sudo kex kill
```

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown Win-KeX and `vnc-server` in kali linux and install `dbus-x11`

```
sudo apt install dbus-x11
```

Answer (score -2):

Had the same issue. Try doing this in powershell:

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl -d {LINUX NAME}
```

then run `sudo kex`.